# maven: how to export packed sources with jar in "package" stage

Tags: maven

I have a maven export script (that wasn't been written by me) and I would like to add sources coping as well.
the build script generates 2 outputs using the "maven-source-plugin":
.jar and -sources.jar and they are both exist in the same output folder one next to another.
so far only the jar is being copied, I want the script to place the -sources.jar file next to its jar file

the build pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.mytest</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.00-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>my-parent</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <assembly.format>dir</assembly.format>
        <my.repository.rootUrl>http://maven.my.com</my.repository.rootUrl>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            .
            .
            .
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build> 
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <modules>
    .
    .
    .
    </modules>
    <repositories>
    .
    .
    .
    </repositories>
    <distributionManagement>
    .
    .
    .
    </distributionManagement>
    <pluginRepositories>
    .
    .
    .
    </pluginRepositories>
    <organization>
        <name>My</name>
    </organization>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dist</id>
            <modules>
                <module>../my-assembly/my-runner</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

the export pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.mytest</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.00-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../../my-parent</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>my-runner</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        .
        .
        .
    </dependencies>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <id>create-runner</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>runner</finalName>
                                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            <descriptors>
                                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/runner.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

the runner file (referenced by the export pom):

```
<assembly
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <formats>
        <format>tar.gz</format>
        <format>zip</format>
        <format>dir</format>
    </formats>
    <id>runner</id>
    <dependencySets>
        .
        .
        .
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}    </outputFileNameMapping>
            <includes>
                <include>org.mytest:*:jar</include>
                <include>org.mytest.systemobjects:*:jar</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*:my-services-so:*</exclude>
                <exclude>*:my-services-tests:*</exclude>
                <exclude>*:my-runner:*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
    .
    .
    .
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: In what order are the plugins executed?  Is the source plugin executing before or after the assembly plugin (noticed they were both in the `package` phase)?  Not sure about the rules in Maven regarding execution order and plugins declared in parent POMs, but if the assembly plugin is executing first, it won't see the sources JAR because it hasn't been attached yet.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at [MNG-1994](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-1994) it seems that in each phase a child's plugins will execute before the parent's.

Your parent POM specifies the source plugin (which generates the sources JAR) in the package phase (this is the source plugin's default phase if not explicitly specified in the execution), but the assembly plugin, which generates the tar.gz, zip and uncompressed finished versions of your project, is run *before* the source plugin because the assembly plugin is declared in the child and the source plugin is declared in the parent.

A solution can be to change the phase the source plugin runs in to ensure it runs before the assembly plugin, something right before the `package` phase such as `prepare-package` will work.  (full list of lifecycle phases is [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html))

In the parent, explicitly setting the phase to `prepare-package` will make it:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This should force the source plugin to execute before the assembly plugin and therefore the assembly plugin should pick up both attached JARs now.

Answer (score 0):

Add another `include` element with the [classifier](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) `sources`:

```
<include>org.mytest:*:jar:sources</include>
```

See the documentation: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet